# How to parse JSON-like file with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this structure of my input data, it is just like JSON but not containing strings. I only need to parse few information from these data

```
{ .appVersion = "1230"; DisplayStrings = ( A ); customParameters = ( { name = Axes;.......(continues)}'''
```

the code looks like this, what happens here is that it matches but search until last appearance of semicolon. I tried all non-greedy tips and tricks that I have found, but I feel helpless.

```
const regex = /.appVersion = (".*"?);/
const found = data.match(regex)
console.log(found)
```

How can I access value saved under .appVersion variable, please?

Comment: I think we'd need more information to answer this. You say this is the structure of the data, but does it ever look different? Will it always look very similar to that?

Comment: What are your eccepted results \ matches?

Comment: If it always looks very similar to that, with insubstantial differences, I would make an array of strings by doing `data.split(';')`, I would make sure all strings have the `{` character removed from the start and all strings are trimmed of white space, and then I would look through the array for a string that starts with `.appVersion` and work from there

Comment: Why is the structure of your input data like this? Is this an external API or you are making one of your own?

Comment: "*it is just like JSON*" I wouldn't say so. You have `=` and `;` and whatever `= ( { name = Axes;.......(continues)}` is. It seems nothing like JSON, aside from having curly brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `.` before `appVersion` since it is a special character in Regex and you can use `\d` instead of `.*` to match only digits. If you want just the number to be captured, without the quotes you can take them out of the parentheses.

```
const regex = /\.appVersion = "(\d+)";/
const found = data.match(regex)
const appVersion = found[1];
```

Comment: Arghh that period on the beginning, totally forgot about it. Thasnk!

Answer (score 1):

```
const string = '{ .appVersion = "1230"; DisplayStrings = (...(continues)';
const appVersion = string.match(/\.appVersion\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"/)[1];
```

If that's what you need...

I'm not sure where the format you're trying to parse comes from, but consider asking (making) your data provider return json string, so you could easily invoke `JSON.parse()` which works in both node and browser environments.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```js
var data='{ .appVersion = "1230"; DisplayStrings = ( A ); customParameters = ( { name = Axes;.......(continues)}';
const regex = /.appVersion = [^;]*/ //regex test: https://regex101.com/r/urX53f/1
const found = data.match(regex);
var trim = found.toString().replace(/"/g,''); // remove the "" if necessary
console.log(found.toString());
console.log(trim);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is looking for `.` which is "any character" in a regex. Escape it with a backslash:

```
/\.appVersion = ("\d+");/
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.*` to capture the value, It's greedy.

You can use something like `\"[^\"]*` - Match a quote, then Any character except quote, as many time as possible.

try

```
const regex = \.appVersion = \"([^\"]*)\";
```

Note that the first dot is should also be quoted, and the spaces should be exactly as in your example.